# Get the first character of string using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, string

Let’s say that my string is:

```
test!
```

I want to get the first character

**t** est!

Also I want to get the last character

test `!`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest is using LINQ:

```
Dim firstChar = str.First()
Dim lastChar  = str.Last()
```

You can use LINQ since a `String` is also an `IEnumerable(Of Char)` implicitely.

- [`Enumerable.First Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx)
- [`Enumerable.Last Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last)

You can also use it like a `Char-Array`([`String.Chars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx) is the default property) and access the first and last char via index:

```
firstChar = str(0)
lastChar  = str(str.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim test As String = "test!"
Dim first As String = test.Substring(0, 1)
Dim last As String = StrReverse(test).Substring(0, 1)
MessageBox.Show("First: " & first & " Last:" & last)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Substring(0, 1)** Returns the `first character of a string`. For Getting the last character you can `reverse` the string using **StrReverse()** and do the same, Like this:

```
Dim str = "test!";
Dim Firstletter = str.Substring(0, 1); //Returns t
Dim Lastletter  = StrReverse(str).Substring(0, 1) //Returns !
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A straightforward suggestion, but if performance is at all relevant, just consider what work is being done internally to get the last character: the entire string must be reversed character-by-character simply to get a single character back.  It's an easy to read, concise solution though if performance is not an issue.

Comment: Yeah Linq option is a better way. But this is a simple and straight solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Reckon this should be fastest.  (Linq is great, but for something like this it's overkill.)

```
    Dim testString As String = "Some test..."
    Dim firstCharacter As Char, lastCharacter As Char

    ' If you want chFirst and chLast as String not Char, just use ToString() on the returned char.
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(testString) Then
        firstCharacter = testString(0)
        lastCharacter = testString(testString.Length - 1)
    End If
```

Comment: Addressing your edit, I'd say the opposite is true. The linq statements clearly expresses the intent of the code, while this example is more muddled in the implementation.

Comment: Frankly, I would often just use Linq too.  The arguments against?  It's (as I understand it) significantly higher overhead.  Often this may be irrelevant, but there is a case for saying it's better to be in the habit of writing more efficient code, especially when there's not much else to choose between them.  Linq also forces a dependency on .Net 3.5; the character index method has existed since v1.0.  But, in the end, it's horses for courses!